# How to ToggleClass fadeIn using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a set of different animation on my website.
For example, I've some HTML tags that contain headers/paragraphs/spans.
I would like to get the headers to change color while fading in and the paragraph to fadein with different color and so on.
here's an example of my html:

```
<button>Toggle Me</button>
<h1>My First Line</h1>
<h2>The Second Line</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span>This is a span.</span>
```

And here's the example of little jquery that I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("h1").toggleClass("blue");
        $("h2").toggleClass("yellow");
        $("p").toggleClass("red");
    });
});
```

that's an example of the CSS:

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Any advice on how to make this work will be much appreciated:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using fadeIn try the following code:
so add the class hide to the html tags as follow:

```
<button>Toggle class</button>
<h1 class="hide">My First Line</h1>
<h2 class="hide">The Second Line</h2>
<p class="hide">This is a paragraph.</p>
<span class="hide">This is a span.</span>
```

Also you will need to define that in css:

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
.gray{
    color: gray;
}
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

And that's how you I would use it in script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("h1").fadeIn(4000).toggleClass("blue");
        $("h2").fadeIn(4000).toggleClass("yellow");
        $("p").fadeIn(4000).toggleClass("red");
        $("span").fadeIn(4000).toggleClass("gray");
    });
});
```

You can always change the 4000 =  4 seconds to whatever you wish.
And change the colors and classes as it's best for you.

Comment: could you please explain why negative?

Comment: While this could work, recommending jQuery animations over CSS transitions for such a trivial example is bad.

Comment: Thanks, and your better answer would be?

Comment: this answer seems to give me really what I was looking for. however, I appreciate you both trying that really help very much

Comment: Your `.fadeIn(4000).removeClass("hide").toggleClass("blue")` makes absolutely no sense. RemoveClass cannot wait for animation queue timing. Since `.hide` is `display: none;` removing a `.hide` is superfluous - toggle blue would be better as `.addClass()` in this case...

Comment: Yup you absolutely right Roko, wrote the code fast without thinking enough. I've edited the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

The following CSS should work with your script for the `h1` tag:

```
h1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}
```

With this you should be able to create the other classes too.

And if you completely want to hide the content initially you could add `display: none;` to the initial CSS and `display: block;` to the classes.

Comment: Although I like best your answer (I'd write the same) - don't forget that **sadly** someone still needs to support IE9. Using CSS3 and jQuery's `fade` with Modernizr or sort would be actually best.

Comment: That's true, but I'd have to go with [Koen's argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973160/how-to-toggleclass-fadein-using-jquery#comment82915961_47973187). In general, I'd use CSS transitions for the browsers that supports it and serve the jQuery fallback to legacy browsers.

Comment: While true, I don’t think OP has that requirement. I myself would leave out animations altogether on IE9..